# I'm trying to create 2 separate excel macros in one goal which is quite tough i know

Tags: vba, excel

**1st Macro**
To go to the cell reference keyed(which is akin to F5), however I'm stuck with the following;

Public Sub Cellgoto()

Application.Goto Reference:="*To be input by user*"

End Sub

*A Separate 2nd Macro*

Purpose: Once the first macro is executed, and go to the rowcolumn that I want, or the designated cell. Then I would love to have another macro to prompt user to paste formulas over to a new text/inputbox. In turn it will pasted to the designated cell(from the first macro). This is really tough, which I'm pretty stuck..

Need angels!

Comment: The reason for the first macro to be created is because it is very hard to have an absolute $ for row and relative for column that must change. Where the (nth jump = 5) for relative column sequentially follows in alphabetical order i.e A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I rather than Sheet1A$4,Sheet1E$4,Sheet1I$4

Comment: Will the user be inputing the cell reference in R1C1 notation, or regular notation?

Comment: What's the purpose of the first macro?  Why not just Ctrl+G ?  For #2, try recording a macro and see if you can modify the resulting code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your Macro. I just wrote the code and tested it and it works. Hope it helps!

```
Sub GotoCellAndEnterFormula()

Dim strGotoCell As String
Dim strFormula As String

    strGotoCell = InputBox("Enter a Cell Reference (ex: B10 )", "Goto Cell")

    If strGotoCell <> "" Then
        Application.Goto Reference:=Range(strGotoCell)
        strFormula = InputBox("Enter a Formula (ex: = SUM(A1,A2) )", "Formula Entry")

        If strFormula <> "" Then
            ActiveCell.Formula = strFormula
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks shiva it will alleviate alot of my manual work. I'll try to see if I can work on #2 macro. God bless you

Comment: @user3022697 My answer code above has the code for #2 macro also. It's these lines. strFormula = InputBox("Enter a Formula (ex: = SUM(A1,A2) )", "Formula Entry")

        If strFormula <> "" Then
            ActiveCell.Formula = strFormula
        End If